# dynamic DataGridView referencing in cell event args

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

So I have a forms app with 4 DataGrids, and I have a `rowleave` event that triggers when a cell is changed, to replace the `backcolor` until the changes are saved to the db. I'm trying to write it so that all 4 grids can use the same events instead of writing the same event 4 times with different grid names. The cell changed event works fine in all the grids but the row leave event does not. Here's what I have so far:

```
private void gridNewBusinessPotential_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var gridList = new List<DataGridView>();

    DataGridView[] grids = {gridBusinessAgentSuppression,
        gridBusinessFollowUpSuppressionData,
        gridFollowUpDescription,
        gridNewBusinessPotential};

    gridList.AddRange(grids);

    var focusedGrid = from dg in gridList
                      where Focused == true
                      select dg;

    focusedGrid.FirstOrDefault().Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
}
```

I get an error in runtime saying that `focusedGrid` is not set to an instance of an object. If anybody knows of a better way to achieve this please inform me. Otherwise, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sender` object tells you what grid you're working on (including the one focused), so why not work with that?

```
private void gridNewBusinessPotential_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as DataGridView)?.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
}
```

Comment: I tried working with the sender (not this way specifically), I still get the same error of it not being set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Something is not right with your code, because the sender can never be `null`. Did you tried this exact way?

Comment: You are correct, I just realized that I am not passing the same sender as the CellChanged event, instead I passed "this" for whatever reason. Your solution was perfect that first time. Thank you very much!